# Find out client time zone in UTC format in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datetime

Is there some way to find out what is the time zone of a user, in UTC format(like UTC+1, UTC+2,...etc)

What I am trying to accomplish is that after user selects UTC time zone from drop down and selects time and date, I want to show date and time values in his time zone (time zone from browser or system).

So if for example user selects: UTC+2 and 13:00 11-03-2016 and his system time zone is UTC than I want to show in some label: In your time that is: 11:00 11-03-2016 (since the UTC is minus 2 hours comparing to UTC+2)

Does somebody has suggestions on how to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Just create new Date object  without specifying the time zone - JavaScript will use the browser's time zone and when getting a date, without specifying the time zone, the result is converted to the browser's time zone.

Please review examples on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Hope it will help. Handling dates in js and angular is a bit tricky;)